# Replace the placeholder text in WordPress default search field

Tags: wordpress

There is a known working method of how to replace the whole WordPress search field, including the placeholder text.

```
function html5_search_form( $form ) {
    $form = '<section class="search"><form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" ><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('',  'domain') . '</label><input type="search" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search website" /><input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Go', 'domain') .'" /></form></section>';
return $form;}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'html5_search_form' );
```

How could I replace only the placeholder default text without altering the form code and the language files?

Comment: Thank you for downvoting. May I please know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Put it into your theme functions file:

```
function html5_search_form( $form ) { 
    $form = '<section class="search"><form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
     <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('',  'domain') . '</label>
     <input type="search" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search website" />
     <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Go', 'domain') .'" />
     </form></section>';

 return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'html5_search_form' );
```